# Jenkins stop "build back to normal" notification

Tags: jenkins, notifications, jenkins-email-ext

I have a question around Jenkins free style job. We're using "Email notification" part of post-build action. So whenever there is a failure, it triggers an email. However it sends another email when the failed job runs to success. I want to stop that. I don't want any email wherever the status of job changes. I know that is possible in pipeline, but is it possible in freestyle job?

Comment: Can you share the configuration you are using today?

Comment: I am using mailer plugin. What exactly you're looking in configuration? For security purpose I can't share entire config.xml file here.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with "Email notification" from [Mailer](https://plugins.jenkins.io/mailer/) plugin.

Altough, it exist [Email-Ext](https://plugins.jenkins.io/email-ext/) plugin which allows a broader set of customizations for email notifications.

For instance, adding an "Editable Email Notification" post-action:

[image: editable notification trigger]